# How to Write a program that checks whether a number input is within the range 21 to 29 inclusive, and displays an appropriate message

Tags: python-3.x

So im completley new to python 3.5 and i've been given this task in my computing class - 'Write a program that checks whether a number input is within
the range 21 to 29 inclusive, and displays an appropriate
message. '
I've looked at some begginer guides but i just can't wrap my head around this. This is the code i've made and have been stuck for atleast 2 hours with.

```
def numbers():
number = (21,30)
print("Please enter your number here: ")
if number < 21:
    print("Number is too small")
elif number > 29:
    print("Number is too big")
else:
    print("Please enter number")
```

It's been giving me this error:

```
Please enter your number here: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    numbers()
  File "C:\Python33\Number hl.py", line 7, in numbers
    if number < 21:
TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < int()
```

Help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because `(21,30)` is a 2-tuple consisting of those two values and you can't compare it to a *single* value that way.

If you want to input a line, you can use `input()`. If you want an integer from that, you can use `int()`.

Something like:

```
number = int (input ("What's your number? "))
```

And, as an aside, I think your final `print` should probably be something like:

```
print ("Thanks, that's a good number")
```

rather than asking for a *new* number.

Comment: I see, thank you very much! That worked just like i wanted it too.

Answer (score 1):

```
def numbers():
  n = int(input("Please enter your number here: ")
  if n < 21:
    print("Number is too small")
  elif n > 29:
    print("Number is too big")
  else:
    print("Please enter number")
```

There's no need of `number` if after you hard code in the `if` tests `21` and `29`.

In addition, if you want to loop untill the input falls in the range you want you should also use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

One of your print statements should be an `input()` function. Use the `range()` function to check if it is between 21-30.

```
def numbers():
    number = range(21,30)
    inp = int(input("Please enter your number here: "))
    if inp not in number:
        print('Not in range of 21 - 30')
    else:
        print('Your number is in range of 21 - 30')
numbers()
```